# Avoiding commutative duplicates in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql, commutativity

**Background**

I am using a MongoDB database to build a medical application, where drug information is stored. There are a few collections in this database, and one of them is for pairwise drug interactions. The data provided to me is on a *per drug* basis. That is, if *A* is a drug that interacts with *B*, *C*, and *D*, I get the pairs `(A,B)`, `(A,C)`, and `(A,D)`. However, I get the same information again when parsing the input data for the drugs *B*, *C*, and *D* in the form of `(B,A)`, etc.

Of course, the corresponding medical information is identical (i.e., *A* interacting with *B* produces the same reactions as *B* interacting with *A*).

**Collection structure**

The collection is structured as each `document` having three fields: `name1`, `name2`, and `description`.

While creating the collection for the first time and populating it, is there a way to index this collection so that `(name1, name2)` is treated as a duplicate of `(name2, name1)` (since they both will have the same `description`)? I would like to not insert such duplicates in the collection.

P.S. I am using the [MongoDB Java Driver 3.8](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/) with MongoDB 4.0.3.

P.P.S Sample document and table index information added below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be9eaeedb9c7a2836cdd48c"),
    "name1" : "Lepirudin",
    "name2" : "St. John's Wort",
    "description" : "The metabolism of Lepirudin can be increased when combined with St. John's Wort."
}
```

I have an ascending index on `name1` and `name2` and a text index on `description`. The above document is inserted for Lepirudin. I would like to avoid inserting the following document for St. John's Wort:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be9eaeedb9c7a2836cdd49e"),
    "name1" : "St. John's Wort",
    "name2" : "Lepirudin",
    "description" : "The metabolism of Lepirudin can be increased when combined with St. John's Wort."
}
```

Comment: I presume you mean the "pairs" are stored in an array? i.e `["A","B"]` in storage shown as JSON form. "Indexes" are not really the solution to "uniqueness" or "order" within an array inside a document. They govern "documents", where entries in the whole collection are enforced to uniqueness. The "problem" thus seems more about how you store/use the the data and also how you perform the updates. But those are the exact details missing from the question. If you actually show those things instead then you might get some input.

Comment: @NeilLunn: No, `name1` and `name2` are two keys in the JSON. There is no array in this collection (in relational DB terms, we can think of it as a table with three columns: `name1`, `name2`, and `interaction_description`).

Comment: How about actually showing sample documents as the comment is meant to be leading you towards then? Your question lacks clarity by not displaying some things. You basically need to "show your work" because it sounds here like you simply have not correctly defined an index, and without evidence otherwise then I'm included to close the question as such.

Comment: The other basic point of the comment was basically that `{ name1: "A", name2: "B" }` is only ever considered "unique" when the exact same thing is attempted to be inserted as a new document. So `{ name1: "B", name2: "A" }` is actually different. With `{ "names": ["A","B"]  }` however, we can very simply and efficiently query the names on creation regardless of the order. You can do that with two fields, but it lacks a little in efficiency. Neither of these has anything to do with a "unique" index either.